# Excel: How to find the last matching value in your table, prior to the active cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the last entry which matches with a value in my current table row.
i.e.

| ID | Name | Surname | Current Salary | old Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lisa | Smith | 10000 |  |
| 2 | Thomas | Phu | 5000 |  |
| 3 | Lisa | Franklin | 90000 |  |
| 3 | Lisa | Smith | 20000 | 10000 (Gets value from first entry, matched by name and Surname) |

In that scenaria I want "old Salary"  to refrence the value of "current salary" of the first entry ID 1 matched by name "Lisa" and Surname "Smith".

Does anyone have a good approach? Rn I am kinda clueless

I have found this code online which is nearly my usecase but not exactly.
Any idea how to modify it for my usecase?

```
Function ItemLookup(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
Dim i As Long
For i = LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
If Lookupvalue = LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) Then
ItemLookup = LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber)
Exit Function
End If
Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any VBA code to accomplish what you are looking for.

In your column "old salary" you want an index match formula.
If you want to match this by "name and surname" you need a column for such data. This can be done by a formula like =B2&C2, or =B2&" "&C2.
The column for such formula could be hidden.

You then need to use the index match on this column.
And you want to find the last occuring dataset.
Read here on how to find nth occurence: https://exceljet.net/formulas/get-nth-match-with-index-match